# Can't read runtime error message in Windows Mixed Reality Headset

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, windows-mixed-reality

I have a very stupid problem.... I have developed an application using Unity3d and the Mixed Reality Toolki using a Windows UWP. It works fine under Unity. However, when build it, compile it with Visual Studio and then run it, I get a couple of red error messages in only one eye and can only real about half of it.....!!!

Any idea how I could either read it or copy and paste it somewhere to read it later?

Comment: Is it possible that in the Build settings you enabled something like "Development build" or similar?

Comment: Possible, will check, but if it's the case having the error messages is a good thing, but in any case how do I read those error messages? They only appear in one eye...